# having hard time with writing this code: need a while function

Tags: while-loop, multiple-conditions

loop to input sales for multiple emplyees, nested for loops to input the sales each week for monthly total.  total sales and emplyee count are accumulated for the month and checked against sales goal.  and there needs to be a count of the number of employees that have been entered.
cant get past line 7, and i'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

Try breaking down the challenge into small tasks. Start with getting your code to loop through the employee list.

Once you are able to loop through, or "iterate" through employees, create your second loop with the sales.

The goal is to get one thing working, then move to the next thing. Don't try to do it all at one time.